# How to decompress a .bz2 file in Google Collab

Tags: compression, bzip2

The answers on this site mostly suggest using bzip2 and bunzip, but I can't install  them in Google Collab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run external commands (shell commands) by prepending them with a `!`, and `bzip2` and `bunzip2` are standard Linux commands and should be pre-installed and available to you.

```
[ ] !bunzip2 path/to/myfile.bz2
```

Or:

```
[ ] !bzip2 -d path/to/myfile.bz2
```

If that doesn't work, you can then use Python code to access the file, in which case the [bz2](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bz2.html) module will be helpful.

```
[ ] import bz2, shutil
    with bz2.BZ2File('path/to/compressed.bz2') as in:
        with open('path/to/uncompressed', 'w') as out:
            shutil.copyfileobj(in, out)
```